# Hadoop FSDataInputStream reuse to read another file

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm using `FSDataInputStream` to read config files and wanted to know if I need to `close()` the `inputStream` and `fs` before reading the second config file:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("file:///path/to/1.conf"), conf);
FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(new Path("file:///path/to/1.conf"));
props1.load(inputStream);
...
...
FileSystem.get(URI.create("file:///path/to/2.conf"), conf);
inputStream = fs.open(new Path("file:///path/to/2.conf"));
props2.load(inputStream);
...
inputStream.close();
fs.close();
```

Is it safe to read another file reusing the same `inputstream` without closing it in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the same `FSDataInputStream` object to read multiple config files.

`FSDataInputStream` opens a `stream` to read data from given file location and actual operation of reading is done when you call `read()` method as in your case is `load`
In your code

```
FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(new Path("file:///path/to/1.conf"));
props1.load(inputStream);
```

An `input stream buffer` is created and `props1.load(inputStream)` will `read` line by line data and stores them in properties `props1` until end of file is reached. So all the lines stored in the `inputStream` `buffer` has been read and is `empty`

And in your next code

```
 inputStream = fs.open(new Path("file:///path/to/2.conf"));
 props2.load(inputStream);
```

The same is repeated as above but with a new file and new `properties` `object`

You can close the `FSDataInputStream` at the end of your code. You should always close it.

I hope its clear

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If it really helped, please upvote as well :) Thanks